# pg_agent выполняет задание но без результатов

Tags: postgresql

Здравствуйте, в целом сабж.
Есть БД postgresql 9.3, в ней 2 таблицы обёртки, написал sql запрос на insert он норм выполняется, внёс его в pgagent, пишет что выполнился всё хорошо, а результата нет. если выполнять вручную результат есть.
Вот сам запрос

```
insert into oracle_billetwba (data_in,nplv,ves,line) select to_timestamp(datetimecontrol,'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS:MSAM')::timestamp without time zone,numbermelt,to_number(regexp_replace(weigth, ',', '.'),'9.99'),'Б'
from mssql_billetwbb_test
where to_timestamp(datetimecontrol,'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS:MSAM')::timestamp without time zone>(select max(data_in)from oracle_billetwba where line='Б');
```

Comment: Там есть и другие задания, они выполняются нормально

Comment: В общем, pgagent не хочет выполнять select в where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал Bash

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u postgres -ppasword psql -d bdname -c "insert into oracle_billetwba (data_in,nplv,ves,line) select to_timestamp(datetimecontrol,'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS:MSAM')::timestamp without time zone,numbermelt,to_number(regexp_replace(weigth, ',', '.'),'9.99'),'Б'
from mssql_billetwbb_test
where to_timestamp(datetimecontrol,'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS:MSAM')::timestamp without time zone>(select max(data_in)from oracle_billetwba where line='Б');"
```